# Facebook Token Renewal

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

My team have developed an App, in which we are using the Facebook Authentication Tokens to retrieve the data from a Facebook and then display it on our App and it is working fine.

The problem which I am facing is that if the Password of Facebook Account is changed then the API Token also become useless, which is an obvious thing.

**But is it possible that when a user updates his/her Facebook Account Credentials then the API Token also gets updated? i.e. I don't want to go through the Token Generation Process, every time the password is changed.**

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

When the user changes their password, all their existing tokens get invalidated *on purpose*.

They will have to go through the login flow again, to create a new token.

Comment: Okay, Let's say I have added Facebook Authentication in my App, so now, in this case, is it possible to Track Profile Token for that Facebook Account?

Comment: No idea what you mean by “track”. If you don’t have a valid access token any more, then you simply need to send the user through the login flow again, to generate a new one.

Comment: What I understood from your Answer is that, "When the Token will Expire, I have to ask the User to Enter the Credentials to Login Again and with that I can get the new API Token"!
Am I right?